# Concatenate regex s+ w+ ... perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have entries like that :

```
    XYZABC------------HGTEZCW
    ZERTAE------------RCBCVQE
```

I would like to get just HGTEZCW and RCBCVQE . 
I would like to use a generic regex.

```
$temp=~ s/^\s+//g;     (1)
$temp=~ s/^\w+[-]+//g; (2)
```

If i use (1) + (2) , it works.
It works i get : `HGTEZCW`, then `RCBCVQE` ...

I would like to know if it is possible to do that in one line like :

```
$temp=~ s/^\s+\w+[-]+//g; (3)
```

When I use (3), i get this result : `XYZABC------------HGTEZCW`

I dont understand why it is not possible to concat 1 + 2 in one line.

Sorry my entries was :

```
    XYZABC------------HGTEZCW
    ZERTAE------------RCBCVQE
```

Also, the regex 1 remove space but when i use regex2, it remove XYZABC------------ .
But the combination (3), don't work.
 i have this `XYZABC------------HGTEZCW`

@Tim  So there always is whitespace at the start of each string? 
yes

Comment: So there always is whitespace at the start of each string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex (1) removes whitespace from the start of the string. So it does nothing on your example strings.

Reges (2) removes all alphanumerics from the start of the string plus any following dashes, returning whatever follows the last dash.

If you combine both, the regex fails because there is no whitespace `\s+` could match - therefore the entire regex fails.

To fix this, simply make the whitespace optional. Also you don't need to enclose the `-` in brackets:

```
$temp=~ s/^\s*\w+-+//g;
```

Comment: Sorry my entries was :
    XYZABC------------HGTEZCW
    ZERTAE------------RCBCVQE
Also, the regex 1 remove space but when i use regex2, it should remove XYZABC------------ , no ?

Comment: @Patrick: Better edit your original question instead of trying to put that into comments. Formatting is more difficult here.

Comment: Thanks the regex $temp=~ s/^\s*\w+-+//g; works.
But i don't understand why this regex doesn't work : $voltemp=~ s/^\s+\w+-+//g;. Maybe there is sometimes there is no space. i will check that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
$Str = '
    XYZABC------------HGTEZCW
    ZERTAE------------RCBCVQE
';

@Matches = ($Str =~ m#^.+-(\w+)$#mg);

print join "\n",@Matches ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the last seven characters of each entry, you could do the following:

```
$temp =~ /.{7}$/;
```